# UIToolBar in combination with pushViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, pushviewcontroller

So, I am kind of a newbie in iOS / Objective-C programming.

My company has a working app made by someone else and I am trying to get an understanding for everything in order to do some minor adjustments.

Right now, I have a problem I can't get around.

Here is the deal:

I have a NavigationController and from my rootView I push other ViewControllers when someone selects rows in a tableView. Every step has its own ViewController.

tableView 1 -> tableView 2 -> tableView 3 -> tableView 4

In ViewController 3 I added a UIToolBar in XIB with 3 buttons. That is the only place where the user can do actions. I added properties for the toolbar and the 3 buttons plus the 3 actions for pushing the buttons.

When the user selects a row in tableView 3, the navigationController pushes the ViewController with tableView 4.

The ViewController of tableView 4 has no UIToolbar in XIB, but the Toolbar from tableView 3 is shown.

How can I hide the UIToolBar again?

I tried:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
```

I think I am missing some kind of basic knowledge :)

I hope that at least some of you can give me a hint how to look at my problem the right way to get the answer.

Thanks

Matthew

Edit:

I missed something reaaaaalllly important!

tableView 3 didSelectRowAtIndexPath is pushing the ViewController for tableView 3 AGAIN with other datasource.

So it is basically:

tableView 1 -> tableView 2 -> tableView 3 (Item) -> tableView 3 (Subitem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put above statement in viewWillAppear method of ViewController of tableView 4

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(id)animated
{
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Like I said in my Edit, I realized that the same ViewController is called. I added a new one for the tableView 4 and added setToolbarHidden in viewWillAppear. Everything works perfect now.